# How to convert bigNumber array to int array?

Tags: solidity, arrays, bignumber

I have a smart contract method that return an array of uint256,

but when I `console.log` the result I got this :

```
[ BigNumber { s: 1, e: 1, c: [Array] } ]
```

How can we convert it to array of numbers?
`toNumber()` work for a single object

Comment: You cycle the array and you apply the `.toNumber()` to each element. or you can use the map function https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map eg: `array.map(x => x.toNumber());`

Answer (score 1):

Consider a deployed contract defined as follows:

```
pragma solidity ^0.4.25;
contract MyContract {
    uint256[] public data;
    function write(uint256 entry) public {
        data.push(entry);
    }    
    function read() public constant returns(uint256[]) {
        return(data);
    }
}
```

After having called `write(1)`, `write(3)` and `write(9)`, the expected outputs are as follows, depending on which *web3* version is in use:

### read() with web3@1.0.0-beta.36

```
MyContract.methods.read().call(function(error, result){
    if(!error) {
        console.log(result);
    }
});
```

#### Outputs:

```
[ '1', '3', '9' ]
```

### read() with web3@0.20

```
MyContract.read(function(error, result){                                                                                                                                    
    if(!error) {
        console.log(result);
    }
});
```

#### Outputs:

```
[ BigNumber { s: 1, e: 0, c: [ 1 ] },
  BigNumber { s: 1, e: 0, c: [ 3 ] },
  BigNumber { s: 1, e: 0, c: [ 9 ] } ]
```

As mentioned by user *mirg*, the results from the `web3@0.20` call must be individually converted into a number or string.

#### Conversion example:

```
var array = [];
for(var i=0;i<result.length;i++){
    array.push(result[i].toString());
}
console.log(array);
```

#### Outputs:

```
[ '1', '3', '9' ]
```

### Appendix

#### array100.js (web3@1.0.0-beta.36)

```
const Web3 = require("web3");
const address = "https://rinkeby.infura.io/";
const web3 = new Web3(address);
const provider = web3.currentProvider;
const contractAbi=[{"constant":false,"inputs":[{"name":"entry","type":"uint256"}],"name":"write","outputs":[],"payable":false,"stateMutability":"nonpayable","type":"function"},{"constant":true,"inputs":[],"name":"read","outputs":[{"name":"","type":"uint256[]"}],"payable":false,"stateMutability":"view","type":"function"},{"constant":true,"inputs":[{"name":"","type":"uint256"}],"name":"data","outputs":[{"name":"","type":"uint256"}],"payable":false,"stateMutability":"view","type":"function"}];
const contractAddress = "0x0000000000000000000000000000000000000000";
var MyContract = new web3.eth.Contract(contractAbi, contractAddress);
MyContract.methods.read().call(function(error, result){
    if(!error) {                                                                                                                                                            
        console.log(result);
    }
});
```

#### array020.js (web3@0.20)

```
const Web3 = require("web3");
const address = "https://rinkeby.infura.io/";
const web3 = new Web3(new Web3.providers.HttpProvider(address));
const contractAbi=[{"constant":false,"inputs":[{"name":"entry","type":"uint256"}],"name":"write","outputs":[],"payable":false,"stateMutability":"nonpayable","type":"function"},{"constant":true,"inputs":[],"name":"read","outputs":[{"name":"","type":"uint256[]"}],"payable":false,"stateMutability":"view","type":"function"},{"constant":true,"inputs":[{"name":"","type":"uint256"}],"name":"data","outputs":[{"name":"","type":"uint256"}],"payable":false,"stateMutability":"view","type":"function"}];
const contractAddress = "0x0000000000000000000000000000000000000000";
var MyContract = web3.eth.contract(contractAbi).at(contractAddress);
MyContract.read(function(error, result){
    if(!error) {
        var array = [];
        for(var i=0;i<result.length;i++){
            array.push(result[i].toString());                                                                                                                               
        }
        console.log(array);
    }
});
```

Hope that helps.

Stay super!

/Javi